# How to Minimize other project windows within the main Project Window?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, .net-4.0

how to manage the Minimize button in the form in C# programming as when the user click on the minimize button the window is minimized at the bottom left which is like in ( Photo Shop ) as when you minimize the other windows it minimized but within the main Form ,, so the user get the ability to know the open windows and also to work on the main .. i am using C# 2008 Programming language

Comment: I do not fully understand your question - do you want to build an [MDI application](http://www.google.com/images?q=.net+mdi+form&hl=en&prmd=iv&source=lnms&tbs=isch:1&ei=67jVTO-MMsiXOuDF3MQJ&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&ved=0CAYQ_AU&biw=1024&bih=599) using Windows Forms?

Comment: yah it is exactly what i wanna do

Comment: There is a [tutorial on the MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983667%28v=VS.71%29.aspx). It uses Visual Studio 2003, but the MDI concept is very much the same in 2008. Good luck!

Comment: I'll put some links in an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two useful links when starting with developing MDI applications using Windows Forms:

A [step-by-step tutorial in VS 2008 and C#](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/57601-using-mdi-in-c%23/)

An outline [example in VS 2003 on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983667%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Windows.Forms, you can set System.Windows.Forms.Form.WindowState property to FormWindowState.Minimized